# How to change the user agent string for java.net.http.HttpClient

Tags: java, http, java-11

I'm using the new `java.net.http.HttpClient` and would like to change the user agent string. By default it sends `Java-http-client/11.0.6` but I'd specify some string on my own.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an existing [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8203771), it's resolved now.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create("https://httpbin.org/headers"))
                .setHeader("User-Agent", "Example user agent")
                .build();
        System.out.println(client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString()).body());
    }
}
```